# Getting Robot Position while Teleoperation

Tags: ros, navigation, turtlebot, move-base, teleoperation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have created a map using gmapping on turtlebot 2. Now, i want to let the user move the robot using teleoperation (meanwhile amcl is also running) and record the coordinate values of the path from where the robot moves. The problem is that when the robot moves using teleop, it does not use move_base due to which I am unable to get the robot's coordinates via topic move_base/feedback. Any ideas on how could I get the coordinates of robot in the reference frame in which my map is running. Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226040/getting-robot-position-while-teleoperation/) by [b2meer](https://answers.ros.org/users/25523/b2meer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2016-02-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [b2meer](https://answers.ros.org/users/25523/b2meer/) on 2016-02-08**:
just checked amcl_pose and that's what I wanted. Thanks a lot for your help. I also wanted to confirm one more thing, if i get the pose from odometry, what reference frame will it be in ?

**Comment by [yasagitov](https://answers.ros.org/users/23174/yasagitov/) on 2016-02-08**:
I guess odometry should be in its own frame `odom`, which support transformation to map with the help from acml

**Comment by [b2meer](https://answers.ros.org/users/25523/b2meer/) on 2016-02-08**:
alright. thanks alot. that was really helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

amcl should publish amcl_pose, isn't it enough?

---

Originally posted by [yasagitov](https://answers.ros.org/users/23174/yasagitov/) with karma: 223 on 2016-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0